# AccuRev, GUI equivalent of incl/excl/lsrules?

Tags: accurev

I can use AccuRev CLI ***incl/excl/lsrules*** to manage include/exclude rules in the stream.
What about the GUI equivalent?

Some of the colleagues prefer GUI. I'd show them how to do the same in GUI.
I've looked through the GUI interface, but didn't found any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a stream, there is an option, at the bottom left, to show include/exclude view.

Comment: Well, the GUI operations on incl/excl rules are not so straight forward. Thank you for the answer, I've finally figured out how to do the same in GUI.